# Word wrap for C++ comments in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator

What I'm looking for is really well explained [in this thread](http://www.zeusedit.com/zforum/viewtopic.php?t=316&sid=e3962b1ee6b785ed7c1d31b4e3fc0450) I found. From it:

```
// This is my comment. But it has been edited 
// so now 
// some lines are long and others are 
// very short. 
// Personally, I find this exceedingly ugly and I really 
// can't tolerate it. However, having to manual fix this 
// sort 
// of thing is undesirable.
```

In the thread they say that emacs has this feature called *M-q*, where it would reformat comments while preserving the starting `//`.

Does Qt Creator have a similar feature? Or if not, is there a (free) standalone program that would allow me to copy and paste the comments in Qt Creator once I write them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Press `Ctrl+E,R` while the cursor is in the comment block. This adds and removes `//` as necessary.

It has a quirk though - if it is a single line comment, it will not add `//` for the new lines. The workaround is to add a `//` line below before pressing `Ctrl+E,R`.

You also need to make sure there is a blank line separating the comment from code, otherwise it will wrap the code as well.

This is bad:

```
int a = 5;
// something something
// something something
int b = 10;
```

It will be wrapped incorrectly to

```
int a = 5; // something something // something something int b = 10;
```

This is good:

```
int a = 5;

// something something
// something something

int b = 10;
```